# Maximum number of rows with web data connector as data source

Tags: tableau-api

How many rows can the web data connector handle to import data into Tableau? Or what is the maximum number of rows which I can generally import?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no limitations to how many rows of data you bring back with your web data connector; performance scales pretty well as you bring back more and more rows, so it's really just a matter of how much time you are OK dealing with.

The total performance will be a combination of:

1. The time it takes for you to retrieve data from the API.
2. The time it takes our database to create an extract with that data once your web data connector passes it back to Tableau.

#2 will be comparable to the time it would take to create an extract from an Excel file with the same schema and size as the data in your web data connector.

On a related note, the underlying database used (Tableau Data Engine) handles a large number of rows well, but is not as suited for handling a large number of columns, thus our guidance is to bring back less than 60 columns if possible.